# Service from cordova plugin not starting anymore

Tags: android, cordova, npm, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I used this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-beacon a year ago to detect nearby ibeacons. That old app is still working. For some reason if I create the same app today with cordova,I see that that plugin was initialised and started monitoring(on the phone), but that s about it. I don't get anything else.

I believe that the new structure of cordova doesn't register the plugin as a service anymore and android doesn't see it as one. Therefore it won't listen for any changes via bluetooth.

I saw that in the old manifest vs the new one:

Old:
[image]

New:
[image]

As you can see the src structure is different too. What might be the problem?

Edit: I have the same android platform and plugin version in both apps and they share the same code.

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    var logToDom = function (message) {
        var e = document.createElement('label');
        e.innerText = message;

        var br = document.createElement('br');
        var br2 = document.createElement('br');
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);

        window.scrollTo(0, window.document.height);
    };

    var initializeBluetooth = cordova.plugins.simplexpbeacon.initialiseBluetooth(function(data){
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        logToDom(JSON.stringify(json));
    });

    var monitor = cordova.plugins.simplexpbeacon.startMonitoring(
        function(data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            logToDom(JSON.stringify(json));
            /*if (json.status === 'OK') {
            logToDom(JSON.stringify(json));
            }*/
        }
    );

    initialiseBluetooth();
    monitor();


    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```